# Como mostrar valores con AJAX al cargar la pagina

Tags: php, html, ajax, highcharts

al momento de entrar a mi pagina index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
<div class="container">    
<select name="inc_sem_zon_per" id="inc_sem_zon_per" >
                <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
                <option value="LIMA">LIMA</option>
                <option value="CENTRO">CENTRO</option>
                <option value="SUR">SUR</option>
                            <?php/*
                           $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                           mysql_select_db("inci",$con);
                           $consulta_semana= mysql_query("SELECT distinct region FROM registro_tecno "); 
                           while($data= mysql_fetch_array($consulta_semana)){
                               $regionx=$data['region'];
                               echo "<option value='".$regionx."' $selected>".$regionx."</option>"; 
                              }*/
                          ?>                 
            </select>
            <select name="fecha" id="fecha">
                <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
                <option value="semanas">semana</option>
                <option value="meses">mes</option>               
            </select>
            <select name="semanas" id="semanas"  onchange="anadir();" hidden>
                <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
                            <?php
                            $acu=1;
                           $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                           mysql_select_db("inci",$con);
                           $consulta_semana= mysql_query("SELECT MAX(semana) as y FROM registro_tecno "); 
                           while($data= mysql_fetch_array($consulta_semana)){
                               $semanax=$data['y'];                                 
                              }
                            while($acu<=$semanax){
                                echo "<option value='".$acu."' $selected>".$acu."</option>"; 
                                $acu++;
                            }
                          ?>                 
            </select>   
            <select name="meses" id="meses" onchange="anadir();" hidden>
                <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
                            <?php
                            $acu=1;
                           $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                           mysql_select_db("inci",$con);
                           $consulta_semana= mysql_query("SELECT MAX(mes) as meses FROM registro_tecno"); 
                           while($data= mysql_fetch_array($consulta_semana)){
                               $mesx=$data['meses'];                                   
                              }
                            while($acu<=$mesx){
                                echo "<option value='".$acu."' $selected>".$acu."</option>"; 
                                $acu++;
                            }
                          ?>                 
            </select>

    <div id="kevin" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"> 
 </div>

</div>
<script >
$( function() {
    $("#fecha").change(function() {
        if($(this).val()==="meses"){
            $("#semanas").prop("hidden",true);
            $("#semanas").prop("value=null",true);
            $("#meses").prop("hidden",false);
        }else{
            $("#semanas").prop("hidden",false);
            $("#meses").prop("value=null",true);
            $("#meses").prop("hidden",true);
        }
    });
});
 </script>
</body>
```

para ver mis graficas, me sale de esta manera...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces para que se muestre la grafica tengo que usar el select,esto me dirije a funciones.js donde uso ajax

```
function anadir(){
   var parametros={
    "inc_sem_zon_per": $("#inc_sem_zon_per").val(),
    "fecha": $("#fecha").val(),
    "meses": $("#meses").val(),
    "semanas": $("#semanas").val(),
}
$.ajax({
    data: parametros,
    url:"ejemplo.php",
    type:"POST",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#kevin").html('<center><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" width="20" heigh="20"></center>');
    },
    success: function(vista){
        $("#kevin").html(vista);
    }
});
```

}

entonces me traeria valores de ejemplo.php:

```
$inc_sem_zon_per=$_POST['inc_sem_zon_per'];
$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
$meses=$_POST['meses'];
$semanas=$_POST['semanas'];
  include("conexion.php");
$estado[0]="En Curso";
$estado[1]="Pendiente";
$estado[2]="Resuelto";


  if ($fecha=="semanas") { 
         $sale="semana";
          $semana_max=$con->query("SELECT MAX(semana) as sem_max FROM registro_tecno ");
          while($row_sem_max= mysqli_fetch_array($semana_max, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
          {
            $me_max= $row_sem_max["sem_max"];
          }

          $limite_inferior=(int)$me_max-(int)$semanas;


        for ($i=0; $i <=2 ; $i++) { 
            $c=0;
          $a="";
          for ($j=$limite_inferior+1; $j <=$me_max ; $j++) { 

          $result_inc =$con->query("SELECT count(incidencia) as ver FROM registro_tecno where (estado='".$estado[$i]."' and region='".$inc_sem_zon_per."' and semana=".$j.") ");
         $rown3=$result_inc->num_rows;
          if ($rown3==0) {
            $a=$a."0,";
                $c++; 
           }else{
            while($row_inc= mysqli_fetch_array($result_inc, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
              {
                $inc[$c] = $row_inc["ver"];
                $a=$a.$inc[$c].",";
                $c++;                
              }
           } 

          }
          $s[$i]=$a;
          echo "estado: ".$estado[$i];
          echo "<br>ver ".$s[$i]."<br>";
        } 

  mysqli_close($con);
}elseif ($fecha=="meses") {
  $sale="mes";
  $c=0;
          $acum_asig="";
          $m_max=$con->query("SELECT MAX(mes) as mes_max FROM registro_tecno ");
          while($row_sem_max= mysqli_fetch_array($m_max, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
          {
            $me_max= $row_sem_max["mes_max"];
          }

          $limite_inferior=(int)$me_max-(int)$meses;


        for ($i=0; $i <=2 ; $i++) { 
            $c=0;
          $a="";
          for ($j=$limite_inferior+1; $j <=$me_max ; $j++) { 

          $result_inc =$con->query("SELECT count(incidencia) as ver FROM registro_tecno where (estado='".$estado[$i]."' and region='".$inc_sem_zon_per."' and mes=".$j.") ");
         $rown3=$result_inc->num_rows;
          if ($rown3==0) {
            $a=$a."0,";
                $c++; 
           }else{
            while($row_inc= mysqli_fetch_array($result_inc, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
              {
                $inc[$c] = $row_inc["ver"];
                $a=$a.$inc[$c].",";
                $c++;                
              }
           } 

          }
          $s[$i]=$a;
        }  

  mysqli_close($con);
}
?>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
    $('#kevin').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Incidencia Por Estado y Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: <?php  echo "' REGION ".$inc_sem_zon_per."'";  ?>
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                <?php for($y=$limite_inferior+1;$y<=$me_max;$y++){ echo "'".$sale." ".$y."',";}?>
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'N° de Incidencias'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.0f} </b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [

        <?php for($h=0;$h<=2;$h++){?>
                       {
                        name: <?php  echo "'".$estado[$h]."',";  ?>
                        data: [
                        <?php 
                            echo $s[$h];

                        ?>
                        ]
                     },
                     <?php }?>

        ]
    });
  });  

 </script>
```

y me muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces mi pregunta seria si al momento de cargar la pagina se puede usar el ajax pero para que me salga una grafica por defecto, y que no me salga en blanco como en la primera imagen que mostre... trate de hacerlo con if-else y un include, pero el problema es que me carga la pagina y demora, pero con el ajax es mas rapido y no carga la pagina...se podra?

Comment: Si usuas Jquery puedes llamar la función que hace la llamada con ajax y genera el gráfico una vez que se cargue la página `$(document).ready(function(){esta_es_mi_funcion();});`

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar la siguiente funcion

```
$(document).ready(function(){

anadir2();

});
```

y anadir2

```
function anadir2(){
   var parametros={
    "inc_sem_zon_per": default,
    "fecha": default,
    "meses": default,
    "semanas": default,
}
$.ajax({
    data: parametros,
    url:"ejemplo.php",
    type:"POST",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#kevin").html('<center><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" width="20" heigh="20"></center>');
    },
    success: function(vista){
        $("#kevin").html(vista);
    }
});
```

cambia default por los datos que quieras poner

Comment: en mi codigo pongo al select de semanas y mese como un onchange="anadir();"...entonces anadir() cumple la funcion de llamar valores, pero como haria con anadir2()

Comment: si tienes ya informacion defualt que quieras cargar al inicio la pones en los default de anadir2 y cargara cuando inicie la pagina

Comment: he agregado tus lineas de codigo a funciones.js pero no muestra nada